# Appendix naming in TOC

Tags: table-of-contents, numbering, appendices

At the moment the appendix is listed in my TOC as shown in the picture below. I now would like to erase the A and just have "Appendix" in the TOC but, at the same time, *not* lose the A.1, A.2, A.3, etc. number of tables in the appendix. How can I do that?

[image]

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Irrespective of how to do that it LaTeX, it has the potential to confuse your readers. Think about them!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number-printing mechanism of the ToC is usually called `\numberline`. It takes a single argument which describes how the number is set in the ToC. You can make this macro gobble its argument (and not do anything with it) from the call to `\appendix` and onward:

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}

%\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
%\AtBeginDocument{\let\stored@numberline\numberline}% Store \numberline
%\AtEndDocument{\addtocontents{toc}{\string\let\string\numberline\string\stored@numberline}}% Restore \numberline
\g@addto@macro\appendix{\addtocontents{toc}{\string\let\string\numberline\string\@gobble}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{A chapter}
\section{A section}

\appendix
\chapter{Appendix}

\begin{table}[ht]
  \caption{A caption}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

The above still maintains the proper numbering of tables (or other hierarchical structures after `\appendix`):

[image]

It also works with [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) if you're using it.

---

Note though that the change is *written* to the `.toc` file. As such, a change to `\numberline` (to `\@gobble`) may affect *all* future uses of it in your document *after* the `.toc` has been read in. So, you may which to re-instate it at the end of the ToC if you're using `\listoffigures` and/or `\listoftables`.

Two constructions that allow for the storage and restoring of `\numberline` is also added in the minimal example. If they're used, your `.toc` should resemble:

```
\contentsline {chapter}{\numberline {1}A chapter}{2}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1.1}A section}{2}
\let \numberline \@gobble 
\contentsline {chapter}{\numberline {A}Appendix}{3}
\let \numberline \stored@numberline
```

Comment: This worked great, however, now the list of figures and list of tables is also included in my ToC. How can I reverse that so that they are not included in the ToC?

Comment: @MadJens: Not as a result of my answer, I'm sure. They must has been there in the first place, so why is that? What packages/class are you using that causes this?

Comment: I used \usepackage[nottoc, notlof, notlot]{tocbibind} , .i.e. options notlof and notlot do not display list of figure and tables in the ToC.